# Magento2: Move an element inside an existing element with catalog_product_view.xml

Tags: magento2

In catalog_product_view.xml file, i need following output like in product details page

````
<div class="product-details">
    <div class="product-info-main">

    </div>
    <div class="product media">
    </div>
</div>

```
````

Comment: you can override layout catalog_product_view.xml and edit it.

Comment: @MichaelHa ok thanks

Comment: Is my comment a solution for you?

Comment: Already i know but i need full code

Comment: This answer is very common, you can easily find it on this site